# How to pull the data from Oracle on quarterly based on EFF_Date

Tags: oracle

I have a data in the table POL_INFO `pol_num,pol_sym,pol_mod,eff_date`. I need to pull the data from it on quarterly basis using EFF_DATE.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you want to query, so here's an example that will hopefully get you started; it counts rows by quarter based on `eff_date`:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(eff_date, 'YYYYQ'), COUNT(*)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(eff_date, 'YYYYQ')
```

The query relies on the `TO_CHAR` date format code `Q`, which returns the calendar quarter (Jan-Mar = quarter 1, Apr-Jun = quarter 2, etc.).

Finally, be warned that the `WHERE` clause is not optimizable. If you have millions of rows you'll want a different approach.